# Android: Insert / update contact photo. weird stuff

Tags: android, image, contacts

I'm trying to insert / update contact photos with the following code:

```
public void ponerFoto()
{
    byte[] bytes = obtenerFoto(mRutaFoto);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    int photoRow = -1;
    String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + mPersonId + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
    Cursor cursor = mC.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null, null);
    int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
    }
    cursor.close();

    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, mPersonId);
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, bytes);
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);


    if (photoRow >= 0) {
        mC.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null);
    } else {
        mC.insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
}


public byte[] obtenerFoto(String rutaFoto)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rutaFoto);
    ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
    byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
    return bitmapdata;

}
```

In the SDK simulator works perfectly, but in my LG P970 with Android 2.3.4 strange things happen:
-A lot of contacts does not add the picture is not updated
-Other times, instead of putting the photo to the correct contact is added to a different one.
-Never fails.

be to have multiple accounts on the phone (skype, facebook, google ...)?

Any idea?

thanks